# Read a specific local file

Tags: javascript

Following javascript method reads a file and displays the contents in output element.

**HTML**

```
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<div id='output' />
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var openFile = function (event) {
            var input = event.target;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {
                var text = reader.result;
                var node = document.getElementById('output');
                node.innerText = text;
                console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
            };
            reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
        };
    </script>
```

**Requirement:**
My requirement is to read a specific local file. For example,

```
openFile('test.xml');
```

I have tried change the method but always get error. Can someone help?

Comment: [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file) readTextFile("file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt");

Comment: @Faisal would you mind flagging this as a duplicate?

Comment: The link uses XMLHttpRequest, which is obsolete and get error.